# Problem with onclick firing to incrementally increase the size of each image in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to write a script in the head element of my web page where a loop of 10 images will successively increase by 5 pixels each when any one of the looped images is clicked. When the onclick fires, it does create a loop that correctly increases the size for each image, but unfortunately this output gets added to the end of the original loop instead of changing it.

In my head element script, I first tried to use getDocumentById(), then switched to passing the "this" reference to the function, but came up with the same result. I also tried to use addEventListener(), but this didn't work either.

In the head element:

```
<script>        

    function growingPumpkins(e) {           

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {           

            e.innerHTML += `<img src='bandit.png' style="width:${50 + i * 5}px; height:${50 + i * 5}px   "/>`; 

        }

    }        

</script>
```

In the body element:

```
<section>

    <h2>Growing Pumpkins</h2>

    <p id="smashingPumpkins" onclick="growingPumpkins(this)" ></p>      

    <script>           

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                

            document.getElementById("smashingPumpkins").innerHTML += "<img src='bandit.png' />";

        }


    </script>

</section>
```

I wanted to initially create an HTMLCollection in the head element to achieve the desired result, but wasn't able to get any output when trying that. Right now, I still get the onclick loop concatenated to the original loop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Template Literals assertions `${foo}` you need backticks, not quotes

```js
`Text ${foo} text`
```

`e.innerHTML +=` is used to append to the current HTML of an element, not to increase the size of an element.

Instead:No need for `for` loops. Use `document.querySelectorAll()` and `NodeList.forEach()` with `Element.addEventListener()` to attach a desired function to the Event handler

```js
const grow = ev => {
  const el = ev.currentTarget;
  el._w = el._w ? el._w + 10 : 40;
  el.style.width = `${el._w}px`;
}; 

document.querySelectorAll(".grow").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', grow));
```

```css
.grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30px;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img class="grow" src="https://i.imgur.com/GDUJj6t.jpg">
<img class="grow" src="https://i.imgur.com/GDUJj6t.jpg">
```

#### Increment size of multiple images **on parent click**:

```js
const el_backyard = document.querySelector("#backyard");
const tot = 5;       // total images
const min_size = 30; // px
const step = 10;     // increase by 10 px

// PLANT
for (let i=1; i<=tot; i++) {
  const el = new Image();
  el.src = "https://i.imgur.com/GDUJj6t.jpg";
  el.style.width = `${step * i}px`;
  el_backyard.append(el);
}

// GROW
const grow = ev => {
  el_backyard.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
    img.style.width = `${img.offsetWidth + step}px`;
  });
}; 

el_backyard.addEventListener('click', grow);
```

```css
#backyard > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="backyard"></div>
```